# Pointer illegal access to array on PIC32

Tags: c, pointers, exception, pic32

I'm working on a project and I need to access an array of **unsigned char** that represent fonts for LCD. Some fonts need two to three bytes to represent each row. So I was trying to implement code like this

```
const unsigned char font[]={...};//array of n bytes representing a font.
uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t*)font;
void lcd_map(){
    //get 4 bytes of array as int to map LCD
    int val = *(int*)ptr;
}
```

Dereferencing the pointer as **int** isn't working, debugging the code leads to an exception of type illegal access of address.

After some experimentation, I got it working when the assignment of the pointer and the dereferencing are done in the same scope:

```
const unsigned char font[]={...};//array of n bytes representing a font.
uint8_t *ptr;
void lcd_map(){
    //get 4 bytes of array as int to map LCD
    ptr = (uint8_t*)font;
    int val = *(int*)ptr; 
}
```

But I need to implement the function as the former code. What may be the issue? I tested the former code on an online C compiler and it works without a problem.

Comment: My general advice is to not pigeon-hole yourself into one implementation. That becomes an X/Y problem for the community. Instead, state your intent and show what you've done. Then, you'll likely get better advice and learn other ways of tackling the problem.

Comment: *Dereferencing the pointer as `int` isn't working*  Because doing that is always [a strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and undefined behavior.  Whoever taught you to write code like that doesn't really understand C.  You can't treat memory as something it's not (except you can always treat anything as `[un[signed]] char`).  In this case you're trying to treat memory that's actually `unsigned char` as an `int`.  **You can't do that safely**.  Full stop. Anyone who tells you otherwise is just plain wrong.

Comment: `const unsigned char font[]` lacks certain `int` alignment.  Step 1: fix that per @Rafael.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't thinking about the strict aliasing. Instead, I used `memcpy()` and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to create a union that allows you to access the individual bytes as well as the 4-byte whole:

```
union {
        uint32_t whole;
        uint8_t parts[4];
} font;

void lcd_map(void)
{
        uint32_t data = font.whole;
        uint8_t byte2 = font.parts[1];
}
```